# EpiServer : How to Check Whether Page Exists?

Tags: episerver

Is there a way to gracefully check whether a page exists in EpiServer CMS 5 (given a pageId integer) **without** having to catch the `PageNotFoundException` thrown by

`DataFactory.Instance.GetPage(pageReference)`

(EpiServer will happily create a PageReference using a non existing pageId).

Surely I can check whether a page exists without throwing an exception or doing a massive loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[EPiServer CMS 5 R2 SP2]
No, not without bypassing the page cache and that is more expensive than catching the exception.

Comment: Cheers Frederik. I thought not.

Answer (score 0):

I find it nice to do the catching in an extension method:

```
public static bool TryGetPage(this PageReference pageReference, out PageData pd)
{
    try
    {
        pd = DataFactory.Instance.GetPage(pageReference);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        pd = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not return the `PageData` object instead of a bool and let the exceptions return as a null?

Comment: I like the look of the code: PageData pd; if (pageRef.TryGetPage(out pd)) { // use pd } Nicer than having to null check.

Answer (score -3):

There is a static method of PageReference which should help:

```
PageReference.IsNullOrEmpty(pageLink)
```

Comment: PageReference.IsNullOrEmpty() only checks if the passed page reference is constructed correctly or not null, not if the acutal page exists or not.